# Sending an SMS message via one click?

Tags: sms, home-screen-shortcuts

Can I send an SMS message via one click or touch?

Can I have an icon or shortcut that would let me send an SMS message to a certain phone number with predefined text?

Comment: not exactly a duplicate but pretty close: [How can I attach a default SMS template text to a specific contact number?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8156/how-can-i-attach-a-default-sms-template-text-to-a-specific-contact-number)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) app will let you do this (and much much more)

Once installed, add a "Task" widget to your homescreen, and have it run a "Send SMS" action.  This lets you specify the target of the SMS, as well as the full body of the message.

Answer (score 1):

5 years have past - I think perhaps the app [OneClickSMS](https://apkpure.com/send-sms-message-in-one-click/com.utopia.oneclicksms) is a better fit for this task now (unfortunately it has been retired from Google Play but it's still available on mirrors with the original APK name *com.utopia.oneclicksms*).

It creates an icon on your home screen, and when you hit it, it sends an SMS with a single click. Very convenient.