# How can I attach a default sms template text to a specific contact number?

Tags: sms

I would like to **attach a certain text** to a specific contact number to used as **default text** when I want to send a text.

*In other words*: as soon as I select a contact to send a text message to: some default text should already be inserted.

I am aware that programs like `tasker` can do this. Although undoubtedly a very impressive program, it seems to me to be an overkill to install a program like this, just to have this one feature.

Is this possible ?

Comment: not exactly a duplicate but pretty close: [Sending an SMS message via one click?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8153/sending-sms-via-one-click)

Comment: @Daniel: I saw the question after I posted mine, but I think my question is indeed slightly different (certainly when looking at the question text it self). So I decided to leave me question be.

Comment: I kind of agree - I placed the link in case someone was looking for either answer.

Comment: I can't actually see a way of doing this with Tasker.  With Go SMS you can set up per-contact Signatures, which is *almost* what you want, but not quite (you can't edit the signature, it just gets appended to whatever you type)

Answer (score 1):

[chompSMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.p1.chompsms) by Delicious Inc. available from Google Play Store.

> with lots of extra features like Quick Reply, Quick Compose, Scheduled Messages, Passcode Lock, Privacy, Easy Pick Emoji's, **Templates (text snippets)**, Signatures, heaps of customization options (notifications, ringtones, colors, fonts, wallpapers), Blacklisting and much more!

<sup>May diverge a bit from your precise goal, but works like a charm to achieve the same end.</sup>

You can use this app to have a ton of templates prepared, and use them when texting someone.

Instead of typing over and over the same thing on different messages, either at the beginning, middle or end of a text, you just long tab the message body and pick up the desired template.